# mysql join with condition on clause return null

Tags: mysql

I am querying a parts table in my database where I am left joining inventory and other tables so that if the inventory does not have the quantity I can return "Not available" in place of quantity.

Here is my query:

```
select partNumber, 1 as QtyRequired, IFNULL(inventory.Quantity,0) as QtyAvailable,IFNULL(Stagename,"Not Available") as Stagename,IFNULL(LocationName,"Not Available") as LocationName  from parts
left join inventory on parts.partID = inventory.partid
left join locations on inventory.LocationID = locations.LocationID
left join stages on inventory.StageID= stages.StageID and stagename <> 'green'
where assembly is true and parts.partID = 7732
```

The problem is that I do not want to return quantity when stagename is green.

Now I have one row of partID 7732 in my database which in stage green but it does have a location. The result I am getting is:

```
PartNumber QtyRequired QtyAvailable StageName     LocationName
SENSODINE2   1            150       Not Available  Warehouse5
```

What I was expecting was

```
PartNumber QtyRequired QtyAvailable StageName     LocationName
SENSODINE2   1            0       Not Available   Not Available
```

To achieve that I thought I would do something like:

```
select partNumber, 1 as QtyRequired, IFNULL(inventory.Quantity,0) as QtyAvailable,IFNULL(Stagename,"Not Available") as Stagename,IFNULL(LocationName,"Not Available") as LocationName  from parts
left join inventory on parts.partID = inventory.partid and stagename <> 'green'
left join locations on inventory.LocationID = locations.LocationID and stagename <> 'green'
left join stages on inventory.StageID= stages.StageID and stagename <> 'green'
where assembly is true and parts.partID = 7732
```

But doing this gives me:

> Error Code 1054: Unknown column 'stagename' in 'on clause'

Comment: Why `Stagename` in the select clause is capital cased, but not in the on clause?

Answer (score 1):

Just move `stagename` to the where clause

```
SELECT partNumber,
       1                                     AS QtyRequired,
       IFNULL(inventory.Quantity, 0)         AS QtyAvailable,
       IFNULL(Stagename, "Not Available")    AS Stagename,
       IFNULL(LocationName, "Not Available") AS LocationName
FROM parts
         LEFT JOIN inventory ON parts.partID = inventory.partid
         LEFT JOIN locations ON inventory.LocationID = locations.LocationID
         LEFT JOIN stages ON inventory.StageID = stages.StageID
WHERE assembly IS TRUE
  AND parts.partID = 7732
  AND Stagename <> 'green'
```

I don't believe you can join on an aliased fields, but you can always filter them later.

Also, to avoid ambiguity, it would be good practice not to name the alias the same as the name of the field you are filtering. Calling it `stageNameReadable` or something similar will help you to treat the field different, as it will have different properties being a calculated field.

Comment: This will *remove* all rows with `Stagename = 'green'`, not give a result like OP requires (where the row is still returned but values are cleared)

Comment: Yeah @Nick is right. Adding it to where clause will remove all rows with stagename `green` and will never return the `Not Available`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your expected output, you can achieve same like below:

```
select partNumber, 1 as QtyRequired, IF(inventory.Quantity is null or stagename = 'green',0,inventory.Quantity) as QtyAvailable,IFNULL(Stagename,"Not Available") as Stagename,IFNULL(LocationName,"Not Available") as LocationName  from parts
left join inventory on parts.partID = inventory.partid
left join locations on inventory.LocationID = locations.LocationID
left join stages on inventory.StageID= stages.StageID
where assembly is true and parts.partID = 7732
```

I have updated the `if` condition and if you do not want data with stagename `green` then you can also have `stagename <> 'green'` condition in `where` clause.